# Verify from this proof of $\lim x^2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

**Preliminary Analysis:**

$$|x^2-4| = |(x-2)(x+2)| = |x-2|<\frac{\varepsilon}{|x+2|}$$

Since $\delta$ can not depend on $x$ then

choose a small $\delta_i$ such that $$\delta_i<\frac{\varepsilon}{|x+2|}$$ where $\delta_i$ does not depend on $x$

Impose $|x-2|≤ 1$ then

$$-1 ≤x-2 ≥1$$

$$ = 1 ≤x ≥3$$

$$= 3 ≤x+2 ≥5$$

$$ = -5<3 ≤x+2 ≥5$$

$$ = |x+2| ≤5 $$

put $\delta_i = \frac{\varepsilon}{5}$

then $$\delta_i = \frac{\varepsilon}{5}<\frac{\varepsilon}{|x+2|}$$

Now we have 
$$|x^2-4| = |(x-2)(x+2)| < 5.|x-2| = |x-2|<\frac{\varepsilon}{5}$$

**Formal proof:**

$\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)=x^2\iff (\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0):0<\lvert x-2\rvert<\delta = \min({1,\frac{\varepsilon}{5}})\implies\bigl\lvert x^2-4\rvert = |(x+2)(x-2)| < 5.|x-2|<5 \frac{\varepsilon}{5} = \varepsilon$

Comment: looks good to me.

Comment: It is not true that $|(x - 2)(x + 2)| = |x - 2|$ unless $|x + 2| = 1$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig - $|x^2-4| = |(x-2)(x+2)| < 5.|x-2| < |x-2|<\frac{\varepsilon}{5}$                                                                                                           is it okay now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to show that $\lim_{x \to 2} x^2 = 4$.

We know that if $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$, then for each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $0 < |x - a| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.

In this case, we claim $L = 4$, so given $\epsilon > 0$, we wish to find $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $0 < |x - 2| < \delta$, $|x^2 - 4| < \epsilon$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$.  Observe that 
$$|x^2 - 4| = |(x + 2)(x - 2)| = |x + 2||x - 2|$$
Let $\delta_1 = 1$.  If $0 < |x - 2| < 1$, then 
$$-1 < x - 2 < 1 \implies 1 < x < 3 \implies 3 < x + 2 < 5 \implies |x + 2| < 5$$
Set $\delta_2 = \frac{\epsilon}{5}$.  Let $\delta = \min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$.  Then if $0 < |x - 2| < \delta$, 
$$|x^2 - 4| = |x + 2||x - 2| < 5|x - 2| < 5 \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{5} < \epsilon$$
so we may conclude that $\lim_{x \to 2} x^2 = 4$.

**Note:**  You made some errors in your preliminary analysis.

Your claim in the first line that $|(x - 2)(x + 2)| = |x - 2|$ is only true when $|x + 2| = 1$.  It looks like you were attempting to isolate $|x - 2|$ without paying attention to what your equals signs meant.

If $|x - 2| \leq 1$, then $-1 \leq x - 2 \color{red}{\leq} 1$.  You reversed the direction of the inequality in that line and the following three lines.

Also, you should not write $\delta_i$ for two different values of $\delta$.  Name each one separately, then take their minimum to ensure that all the bounds are satisfied.

Comment: Is it okay to conclude that $\delta_2 = \frac{\varepsilon}{5}<\frac{\varepsilon}{|x+2|}$ ?

Comment: By choosing $\delta = \min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$, we ensure that $\delta < 1 \implies |x + 2| < 5$.  If $\delta_2 \geq 1$, then we cannot conclude that $|x + 2| < 5$, which is why we need to take the minimum of $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Your second inequality is wrong -
it should be
$-1 \le x-2 \le 1
$
or
$3 \le x+2 \le 5
$
(adding 4 to each term).

Therefore
$3 \le |x+2| \le 5$.

You cen then use this
as you need.